# Show dialogfragment only while holding the button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I want to show a dialogfragment in a fragment but only while holding the button, so that it gets dimissed on user releasing touch. But when I show the dialogfragment, it removes the focus from the button and is not dismissed on release. Anyway this is what I have tried so far :

```
        c1b1= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.card_b1);
        c1b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                Rdialog_Fragment dialogFragment = new Rdialog_Fragment ();
                FragmentManager fm = r2_fragment.getFragmentManager();
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                   // Rdialog_Fragment dialogFragment = new Rdialog_Fragment ();
                    dialogFragment.show(fm, "Sample Fragment");
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    dialogFragment.dismiss();
                }
                return false;

            }
```

[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Once you open a Fragment/DialogFragment on top of Fragment/Activity it automatically move the focus from currently opened Fragment/Activity to the newly opened Fragment/DialogFragment.

Comment: is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to achieve. Can you please add some graphics/screenshots stating what you want?

Comment: like this. I would find it strange if there was no way to do this the with standard libary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of showing UI like this way can be achieve by [PopupWindow.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) However I am not sure about focus because this might also release the focus from current view. Just try it.

There is one more hack you can do by adding the the view on top of fragment layout at creation time or by adding it inside fragment xml but set it's visibility property to INVISIBLE initially. Once you detect press event set it's visibility property to VISIBLE and once you detect the release event set this view INVISIBLE again. That way focus might not clear automatically from the current view.

Comment: Popupwindow worked. 
If anyone has the same problem use a poupwindow and set the focus to false sadly you cant do that with dialogfragments

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called 3DTouch effect and you can use the following implementation by Shalskar, called PeekAndPop.

You can find the library and the needed instructions in its [repository on Github.](https://github.com/shalskar/PeekAndPop)